# Meaning of 'modal' in modal ‘argument from contingency’

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

> Like most arguments for the existence of God, the cosmological argument exists in several
>   forms; two are discussed here: the temporal, kalam cosmological argument (i.e. the fi rst
>   cause argument), and the **[modal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/modal)** ‘argument from contingency’. The main distinguishing
>   feature between these two arguments is the way in which they evade an initial objection
>   to the argument.
>   (Source: ‘The cosmological argument’ by Tim Holt, www.philosophyofreligion.info )

Source: p 116, *Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*, Mark Shepherd

> From the link above: 1. Relating to [mode](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mode) or [form](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/form) as opposed to substance.

The abstractness confuses me, so I tried to continue to the definitions of 'mode' and 'form'. Yet they are also abstract and too numerous for me to determine the best fit. Please explain the steps or thought processes, so that I can try to resolve this myself in the future?

Comment: According to the dictionary you link to, it should be #5, which defines *modal* in the context of Logic (or Proposition Logic, in this case, I believe). I searched for the term "argument from contingency" on the web for a bit and found the first section here: http://home.southernct.edu/~gillilandr1/phil201/Aquinas.htm, relatively easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This type of philosophical and/or theological discussion often uses technical or, at the least, hyper-formal language, to the point where many native English speakers will not be able to understand them on a first reading.

What this means, in practical terms, is that with this type of language, don't stop with the first definition. Keep reading, and if there is a definition that is more closely related to the subject matter, use that definition.

In this instance, there is such a definition: definition 5 in your source, which reads:

> 5. Logic (Of a proposition) in which the predicate is affirmed of the subject with some qualification, or which involves the affirmation of possibility, impossibility, necessity, or contingency.

The passage is discussing a question of formal logic; therefore, when you see that there is a dictionary definition marked "logic," look closely at that before you spend too much time beating your head against the first definition.

In this case, the fact that definition 5 and the clause in question both include the word "contingency" is a strong indication that definition 5 is the right one.

The lesson is: don't get so hung up on the first definition that you miss a definition that makes the most sense in the context of the passage.